# can't login to website with getelementsbyid

Tags: powershell

Searching throughout stackoverflow and google, there's one common way of logging into a website - but the website i'm trying to log into, this does not work

the typical code:

```
$username = 'username'
$password = 'password'

$ie = new-object -comobject internetexplorer.application
$ie.visible=$true
$ie.navigate("example.com")

$usernamefield = $ie.document.getelementsbyid("username")
$usernamefield.value("$username")

$usernamefield = $ie.document.getelementsbyid("password")
$usernamefield.value("$password")

$link = $ie.documents.getelementsbyid("login") 
$link.click()
```

This doesn't work for my particular website, because when i inspect the website, there is no 'id' that shows in these sections.

here is what DOES show up: 
For User element:

```
<input type="text" name="username" maxlength="96" size="20" value="" class="input">
```

For password element:

```
<input type="password" name="password" maxlength="40" value="" class="input">
```

For login button:

```
<input type="image" src="data:image/webp;b" alt="Sign In" title=" Sign In ">
```

Is there another way of going about populating the username & password fields, as well as another way of clicking the 'login' button? Or is there some way of locating the ID's of these elements? (as i imagine that they'd have to have an id)

Answer (score 0):

you can try setting values with name

```
$ie.Document.getElementsByName("username") | %{$_.value = "test"}
```

and for login:

```
($ie.Document.getElementsByTagName("input")) | ?{$_.type -eq "image"}|%{$_.click()}
```

hope this helps